# EF Core 6, { character in an SQL VALUES() block is causing string not in a correct format exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ssms, visual-studio-2022

This one can't be correct, probably is somehow a mis-configuration of EF Core in our project.

Background: We have to export an Oracle DB from Aqua Data studio to a file.  I have been manually transposing the export from Oracle to SQL Server.  We came up with the idea of putting the manual process into a Visual Studio project.

From the project, certain strings in the VALUES() section of some INSERT INTO "SomeTable" blocks fail.

In all cases the same code copied over to SSMS works with no modification to it.

This unit test does prove that the { character in the string throws an exception.  Removing it from the string, the ExecuteRawSQL() method will now insert the data. I've put Bold / Italics around the {.

We are running the latest SQL Server Express, on local host.  EF Core 6, .Net Core 6.

The entire input string for ANSWER_TEXT is after the Test Method code block.

I've tried escaping the {, etc.  Also putting a space between { and Project.  Not that I thought this would fix it, just to rule it out.

The { causing the issue can't possibly be right.  The same block with the entire string will insert via SSMS.

It's got to be a Visual Studio project or EF Core config issue, something like that.

It's got me stumped -- didn't expect to trim this string down and be able to duplicate this malfunction.

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void Test_CE_USER_ANSWERS()
    {
        File.Delete(@"C:\ProjectsTFS-DOIT\Online CE\Docs\New_TSQL_DB\Test_CE_USER_ANSWERS.txt");
        List<string> sqlDataStatements = new ();
        string ceUserAnswers = @"INSERT INTO ""CE_TRANSMITTAL_ANSWERS""(""FORM_ID"", ""TRANSMITTAL_ID"", ""QUESTION_ID"", ""ANSWER_ORDER"", ""ANSWER_TEXT"") 
            VALUES(9804, 1, 808, 0, 'A history/architecture memo to file dated 3/25/ 2021 has been uploaded to Environet ***{*** Project File&gt;Cultural Resources&gt;Project ')
            ";
        sqlDataStatements.Add(ceUserAnswers);
        using (CETESTContext ctx = new())
        {
            foreach (string statement in sqlDataStatements)
            {
                try
                {
                    ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(statement);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ProjectsTFS-DOIT\Online CE\Docs\New_TSQL_DB\Test_CE_USER_ANSWERS.txt", "Exception Details: \n ================ \n" + ex.ToString() + "\n ================  \n" + "SQL Statement: \n ================ \n" + statement + "\n ================ \nEnd of Exception and Statement Message \n ================ \n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the entire input string:

```
'<div>There are no previously recorded archaeological sites within the project APE. The project area is located within a suburban corridor with commercial and dense residential development. Areas of new right-of-way beyond the existing operational right-of-way have been disturbed by modern development including commercial development, gas stations, driveways and streets, parking areas, underground utilities, sidewalks, and residential development to the northeast and east. No further archaeological investigations are recommended.</div><div><br></div>The project area is largely developed with commercial buildings less than 50 years old. A history/architecture memo to file dated 3/25/ 2021 has been uploaded to Environet {Project File&gt;Cultural Resources&gt;Project Information&gt;Memo-to-File History Architecture]. No history/architecture properties within the APE were recommended as eligible for the NRHP. Based on the scope of the project and review of the project APE, no additional research is recommended for history/architecture properties, and no NRHP-listed or eligible properties will be affected by the project.'
```

### Edit 1

Regarding this from *Lasse V. Karlsen* from the comments:

> If I'm not mistaken, whole ExecuteSqlRaw implementation is an anti-pattern because it uses the same syntax and features as string.Format, thus promoting SQL concatenation. Try doubling up the brackets, {{ instead of just {, see if this ends up inserting with just 1 {

This does work.  But we have some 4.9 million lines of code with INSERT INTO ... VALUES(), any of the values might have { or } which need to now be {{ or }}.

Would prefer not to alter data although technically this really does insert one { or }.

Is there some way to tell EF to not worry about {} characters?  That would be much easier.

### Edit 2

I wasn't crazy about doing a blanket replace of { with {{, } with }} but this works.

Here is our code for our replacements -- takes out unneeded Oracle syntax and now replaces {}:

```
        private static string RemoveOracleSyntax(string statement)
    {
        string cleanStatement = statement;
        if (cleanStatement.Contains("TO_DATE"))
        {
            cleanStatement = cleanStatement.Replace("TO_DATE(", "");
            cleanStatement = cleanStatement.Replace(",'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')", "");
        }

        if (cleanStatement.Contains("TO_CLOB"))
        {
            cleanStatement = cleanStatement.Replace("') || TO_CLOB('", "");
            cleanStatement = cleanStatement.Replace("TO_CLOB(", "");
            cleanStatement = cleanStatement.Replace("'))", "') ");
            cleanStatement = cleanStatement.Replace("'),", "', ");
        }

        if (cleanStatement.Contains("{"))
        {
            cleanStatement = cleanStatement.Replace("{", "{{");
        }

        if (cleanStatement.Contains("}"))
        {
            cleanStatement = cleanStatement.Replace("}", "}}");
        }

        return cleanStatement;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use such code to begin with. Don't concatenate strings to generate a query, that's how SQL injection attacks happen. EF Core is an ORM, not a data access library, and yet that's how you try to use it. If you used EF Core properly, all you'd have to do was create some `Answer` objects, add them all to the DbContext with `DbContext.Add` and finally persist all changes with a single call to `SaveChanges`

Comment: If you wanted to execute a direct SQL query you'd still have to use parameters instead of concatenating strings. Instead of executing one INSERT after another, you should create a single `INSERT` statement with multiple values in the `VALUES` clause. Right now you pay the overhead of executing a new INSERT every time

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, whole `ExecuteSqlRaw` implementation is an anti-pattern because it uses the same syntax and features as `string.Format`, thus *promoting* SQL concatenation. Try doubling up the brackets, `{{` instead of just `{`, see if this ends up inserting with just 1 `{`.

Comment: Panagiotis -- good points.  Here's our issue: Aqua Data Studio doesn't allow the options offered.  It makes a singe INSERT INTO ... VALUES() ... GO.  And in one of our tables out of some 47, we have 680,000 records.  I wanted to do the VALUES method you speak of.  There's no way to code that easily given the volume we'd have to transpose.

Now creating answer objects -- that's more complex.  We got more speed out of reading from the whole file into a list of strings separating on GO

I'll look at Lasse's solution and if no joy, try the answer objects.

Comment: Ah -- we're not concatenating.  Sorry.  We're parsing an entire sql file of something like 4.9 million lines, separating on GO.  We get the entire INSERT INTO block.  And then process each such block.

I can see why the code looks that way.  The array is an array of complete INSERT blocks.

Comment: Lasse's answer works.  But now how to figure out what character needs to be doubled ... there has to be something else incorrect someplace in the code, config of project, EF core -- something like that.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I guess a SQL file of 4.9m lines is itself a bad idea. it sounds like you should use a Bacpac or a database backup instead

Comment: Charlieface -- thanks for the input.  We didn't overlook this, of course.  Aqua Data Studio doesn't have an option to make a bacpac or DB backup that ports Oracle over to SQL Server.

For our development at this point, since we're a ways off from our DB Group creating the SQL Server variation of our Oracle DB, we have to use local host copies.

Another issue -- the Oracle design is not correctly normalized and is HUGE :).  The SQL Server variation IS normalized.

And add this -- we're moving from a Spring Ado to EF Core 6.

Our itermediate solution perhaps now makes sense.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the majority of people seeing this question will see it for the first time in it's present form. For a new reader your question doesn't make much sense after all revisions.

Answer (score 1):

The input from Lasse V. Karlsen is the answer.

> If I'm not mistaken, whole ExecuteSqlRaw implementation is an anti-pattern because it uses the same syntax and features as string.Format, thus promoting SQL concatenation. Try doubling up the brackets, {{ instead of just {, see if this ends up inserting with just 1 {.

Our Lead Developer is wants to use ExecuteSQL, not ExecuteSQLRaw.  It was brought up this is no longer in the API.  This supposedly would not fail on a { or } character.

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense and less than insightful. maybe you could improve it